# Why is my global variable causing problems?

Tags: c++

I've been reading about global variables for an hour now and I can't get mine to work. I have two vectors of custom classes, Airport and Flight, which are defined in their respective header files. Then I declare the extern vectors in the Globals.h header which is included in main.cpp. If I leave the code as is, I get a "unresolved external symbol" error for both of the vectors:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class std::vector<class Airport,class std::allocator<class Airport> > airports" (?airports@@3V?$vector@VAirport@@V?$allocator@VAirport@@@std@@@std@@A)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class std::vector<class Flight,class std::allocator<class Flight> > flights" (?flights@@3V?$vector@VFlight@@V?$allocator@VFlight@@@std@@@std@@A)
```

If, instead, I forward declare (like I've been lead to believe is how it should be done) by putting

```
vector<Airport> airports;
vector<Flight> flights;
```

in front of main(), then I get these errors:

```
error C2371: 'airports' : redefinition; different basic types
error C2371: 'flights' : redefinition; different basic types
```

There's also errors given about allocators in vectors, and how one vector is not equal to the other vector. However, I cannot create a vector by typing vector> airport, which is what is suggested. This is mirrored by vector.

The code in my project is below. Any help would be appreciated.

**main.cpp** (simplified):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Globals.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    airports = readInAirports();//returns a vector<Airport>
    flights = readInFlights();//returns a vector<Flight>
}
```

**Airport.h**: (**Flight.h** is similar)

```
#ifndef AIRPORT_H
#define AIRPORT_H
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Airport{
public:
    Airport(string c, string n, int dt, int cc)
        :code(c), name(n),
        departureTax(dt),connectionTime(cc)
    {}
    string toLine();
    string getCode();
    string getName();
    int getDepTax();
    int getConnTime();

private:
    string code, name;
    int departureTax, connectionTime;

};
#endif
```

**Globals.h**:

```
#ifndef GLOBALS_H
#define GLOBALS_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include "Airport.h"
#include "Flight.h"

extern vector<Airport> airports;
extern vector<Flight> flights;

#endif
```

Comment: Those aren't forward declarations.

Answer (score 3):

```
extern vector<Airport> airports;
```

This is a *declaration* of `airports`. It says "Somewhere in the program is a global variable called `airports` of type `vector<Airport>`".

```
vector<Airport> airports;
```

This is a *definition* of `airports`. It creates a global variable called `airports` of type `vector<Airport>`. You cannot have two global variables with the same name, even if they are in different files.

You should know that `#include` effectively copy-pastes the whole contents of the included file into this file. So if you put a definition in a header file, and include that header file in two different source files, then you have two definitions.

The solution is to put the declarations in the header file (with `extern`) and the definitions in *one* source file.

Comment: This was the problem, thank you so so much. I have two .cpp files which both included the "Globals.h" header. This copied them and made it unusable. I thought that, since they were seperate files, I should include the globals header in both of them so they can both see the variables, but in reality it just mucked up the compliler.

Comment: @Nimajik Headers work as if by copy-paste; there's nothing magical about them. Anything you couldn't put in more than one file shouldn't go in a header, and anything you find yourself writing at the start of lots of files should go in a header (usually).

Answer (score 1):

Because you have't ***defined*** them. You only *declared* them (`extern` only declares).

You need to add the definitions for both `airports` and `flights` in a `.cpp` file, like so:

```
vector<Airport> airports;
vector<Flight> flights;
```

Furthermore, `vector<Airport> airports;` is not a forward declaration, it's a definition. To forward declare *variables* you **need** to use the `extern` keyword.